# How to make gauges for racing game?

Tags: game-engine

I am making a racing game and I want to know something:
How do I make gauges for my game. I have 6 gears on car set by states, but only way to visualiate them is game debug. But game debug is ugly- I want to make fancy gauges. How do I make them?

Comment: Hi, please only ask one question at a time. If you want to ask multiple questions then please ask them separately as separate posts.

Comment: But if they are about one and the sme thing, just 2 actions- can't I ask them both in one place? This is easier for me to check for answers...

Comment: I don't think they are the same. One is about visualising data and one is about getting a car to accelerate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the gauges are in an overlay scene, you'll need to establish communication with message sensors.

1. Send a "gearUp" or "gearDown" message to the gauge when the gear changes
2. Put message sensors on the gauge that execute whatever action you desire

Here's a quick sample - use the up and down arrow keys to send messages.
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19279604/static/misc/gauge_example.blend

If the gauges are in the same scene, then it's a whole lot easier.  You can shift+click multiple objects and connect gauge actuators directly to the gear controller.

**EDIT**

There really isn't a good way to copy properties between scenes with logic bricks.  Here's a Python example that can be adapted to your needs:

```
import bge

def copyProps(cont):
    # Get a reference to the object running the script
    own = cont.owner

    # Get a reference to the overlay scene
    overlay = bge.logic.getSceneList()[1]

    # Find the object in the overlay scene
    other = overlay.objects['Speedometer']

    # Copy the desired properties
    other['Text'] = own['speed']

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
    copyProps(cont)
```

Comment: I will check it out, but looks useful. Can you also show, how to make it show property value?(I have "speed" property)

Comment: Unfortunately we can't directly copy properties between scenes with logic bricks.  You're pretty much stuck with sending incremental messages.  I suppose you could send a message for each unit of speed, but that's a bit silly.  I've edited the answer to include a Python script that directly copies properties.

Comment: What object is Speedometer? Which one shouldI call Speedometer?

Comment: Should I make evrything else like in your example? Where should I put the scrip controller?

Comment: Actually, there is an alternate- I can put gauges in the same scene, maybe- I will try...

Comment: Probably for the best.  It's much simpler that way.
The script is just a rough guide.  You'll need to edit the values to fit the object and property names in your file.